# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found. (import sklearn)

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda

When I import `sklearn`, it throws this `ImportError(DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.)`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b7c74cbf5af0> in <module>()
----> 1 import sklearn

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>()
     62 else:
     63     from . import __check_build
---> 64     from .base import clone
     65     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     66 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>()
     11 from scipy import sparse
     12 from .externals import six
---> 13 from .utils.fixes import signature
     14 from . import __version__
     15 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>()
     11 
     12 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
---> 13 from .validation import (as_float_array,
     14                          assert_all_finite,
     15                          check_random_state, column_or_1d, check_array,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in <module>()
     20 
     21 from ..externals import six
---> 22 from ..utils.fixes import signature
     23 from .. import get_config as _get_config
     24 from ..exceptions import NonBLASDotWarning

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in <module>()
     81             return stats.boxcox(x, lmbda)
     82 else:
---> 83     from scipy.special import boxcox  # noqa
     84 
     85 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py in <module>()
    638 from .sf_error import SpecialFunctionWarning, SpecialFunctionError
    639 
--> 640 from ._ufuncs import *
    641 
    642 from .basic import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** you already have a **working** installation of **numpy** and **scipy**, then do this:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

otherwise:

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

finally check for updates:

```
conda update pip
```

Comment: Not using anaconda but getting same error. Could you give a few more details?

Comment: Did not work, that is why I am asking. The latest version might not be the one I want

Comment: I sorted it out. Actually not really sure what I did. I uninstalled and then reinstalled a few things. I use Enthought Canopy so there is a package manager.